# Why does a potential on the reference electrode create an offset on the measure electrode of a pH probe?

Tags: electrochemistry, ph

I am making an analog front end for a pH probe and i encountered a design where creating an offset on the reference electrode, creates an offset on the measure electrode.

How does that work ? Does the charge go through water ?

Experience based on TI application notes : https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa529a/snoa529a.pdf?ts=1619613280868&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.qwant.com%252F

(I don't want to details electronics design because it's not the point)

So here is a pH probe and my mesurement setup: [image]

The voltmeter measure the potential described by the nernst equation.

What happens when I shift the polarity of the reference should be like that:

[image]

Now the voltmeter measure U= Nernst eq + 300 mV

But how having this polarised metal rod in the solution change the measure of the pH electrode ?

My understanding is that the charge on the electrode mooves to the water and to the other electrode ?

But the glass membrane should only let hydrons go through so it "should" be isolated from other change of ions. But it maybe let the current flow from the reference electrode to the measure electrode ?

Comment: How does this differ from what you asked over at the EE stack exchange: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/562549/223146? There was an answer by an extremely high rep user and you accepted that answer, which also had multiple upvotes.

Comment: I asked the question on an electronics context, and i had an unstatisfying answer: "it behaves like a battery". It has to be expected from an electronic points of view.But I want to understand the process behind it. Why does it behave like a battery ? How the potential of the ref electrode interact with the potential of the pH electrode ?

Comment: That EE answer is correct: the pH electrode and reference electrode are simply an extremely high impedance voltaic cell. It can supply only extremely small current, i.e., pA or so. The smaller the better. So offsetting the reference electrode with respect to circuit zero reference (ground) does not change the potential difference between the pH and reference electrodes. But, it allows for use of a unipolar power supply instead of a bipolar power supply, just as that answer said. You might want to look up three and four wire potentiostats for more insight.

Comment: "the pH electrode and reference electrode are simply an extremely high impedance voltaic cell." @EdV So how does that work ? My hypothesis is the AgCl is polarised positively (300mV) so it should have less electrons. So I suppose oxydation is made on the AgCl wire. Those new negative ions should go to water through the porous junction ? Therefore changing the potential of the water. Water being negatively charged, I don't see how it goes through the glass membrane tho...

Comment: This is just a level shifting issue: the pH electrode and reference electrode work as usual. The electrical circuit is referenced to electrical ground, so its output voltage is level shifted by the deliberately added 512 mV. This is **not** a chemistry issue and there is nothing more. Sorry, but your guesses are just off track.

Comment: @Damezumari Please don't cross-post, it is against policy. It appears to me that you have a correct answer on EE and that Ed V has contributed quite a bit to validate that.